# Custom URL Scheme without bringing app in front

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, url-scheme

I'm handling Custom URL schemes like this in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
-(void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSAppleEventManager *appleEventManager = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    [appleEventManager setEventHandler:self
                           andSelector:@selector(handleGetURLEvent:withReplyEvent:)
                         forEventClass:kInternetEventClass andEventID:kAEGetURL];
}

- (void)handleGetURLEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    NSString * URL = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject] stringValue];
    //Do my work with URL
}
```

It is working, but it is possible to not bring the app in front every time I call the custom Scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to handle a URL without your app coming to the foreground.

Depending on what you're doing, it's potentially the case that you could do the work with an [App Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/).  But that's essentially your only other potential solution.